# In what way was Jesus Crucifixion a stumbling block for the Jews? (1 Corinthians 1:23)

Tags: jesus, 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 1:22-23 (NRSV)

> 22 For Jews demand signs and Greeks desire wisdom, 23 but we proclaim
>   Christ crucified, a stumbling block to Jews and foolishness to
>   Gentiles,

**In what way was Jesus crucifixion a stumbling block for the Jews?**

Answer (score 3):

This expression is unfathomable in its profundity, but one of the explanations can be this: in Jewish mainstream expectation the Messiah should have come to restore the Kingdom of Israel, the Throne of David, thus he must have been a political victor, who would subjugate under his just rule not only the nation of Israel, but all nations of earth, cf. Psalm 72:8-11:

"May he rule from sea to sea and from the River to the ends of the earth. 9 May the desert tribes bow before him and his enemies lick the dust. 10 May the kings of Tarshish and of distant shores bring tribute to him. May the kings of Sheba and Seba present him gifts. 11 May all kings bow down to him and all nations serve him."

And suddenly, Jesus, who tells them and proves them by many a miracles that He is the promised Messiah, whom they acknowledge even and receive Him in Jerusalem with shoutings of hosannah and jubilation as the Messianic King (Matthew 21:9) is crucified in front of them! That is to say, is defeated in the most disgraceful manner - as a criminal and lawbreaker. Thus, Jesus belies all their expectations. They have the last desperate hope that maybe He will show His Messiah-ship by miraculously freeing Himself from the cross, defeating His enemies and restoring the throne of David (Mark 15:30), for that is what Messiah is all about! But Jesus dies indeed in the most shameful manner, for it was the worst convicts and criminals that were crucified by the Roman law.

But for the Christians He was the true Messiah and has truly triumphed, the very crucification being His triumph over the real enemies: the sin and, its consequence - the death, for He defeated both on the Cross (1 Cor. 15:55-57) and paved the way to the true Kingdom, not earthly, but heavenly (cf. John 18:36), and not only for a Jewish nation, but to the entire universe or κόσμος (Mark 16:15), and His throne not placed anywhere on the earth, but in each human heart cleansed from sins; in fact each purified human heart, the heart circumcised Spiritually from sins (Romans 2:28-29) becomes His throne, together with the Father (John 14:23) and the Spirit (Joel 2:28; 1 Cor. 6:19). This vision was blocked from non-Spiritually looking Jews by the fact of the crucifixion and death and, hence, failure of earthly political success of Jesus, who said that He was their Messiah; and that is one of the meanings of the Pauline expression that "Jesus as crucified is a stumbling block for Jews": for through beholding non-Spiritually, they have interpreted His triumph and accomplishment as a defeat and failure.

And He still remains such for majority of rabbis and adherents of Judaism, who expect a successful strong politician to come as a Messiah (like they thought such to be Judah the Galilean /1st c./ or Bar Kokhba /2nd c./) and bring the Jewish people to the promised grandeur. But for Christians the grandeur of Jews is Jesus Crucified Himself, for only through crucification of a son of a Jewish woman the entire humanity got access to the eternal Kingdom.

Comment: I believe that Paul may have been thinking  about the Jewish cultural beliefs regarding the manner if his death.

Comment: @ O. Nicolas I do not understand what do you mean in "Jewish cultural beliefs" and Paul's attitude to them.

Comment: @ Levan Gigineishvilli Taking into consideration the culture and the manner of his death, people believed that  this revealed his character, a roque.
One of the " lestes"  said to the other  we deserve what we are getting, they were violent criminals, that stole , and killed. Others deserving such punishment were for treason against the state, Jesus was such a man.  Being impaled was a shameful way to die, and therefore  people did not want to be associated with him, a cause to stumble.

Answer (score 0):

It's because someone who was crucified is considered to be cursed (hung on a tree)… how can you have a cursed Messiah? The paradox is that He is sinless... it's better to present Him (Yeshua/Jesus) as a martyr for the nation - like other Jewish martyr's (see tzaddikim or righteous ones) of Jewish history. In other words, he wasn't cursed by G-d but took on our sin - just like the animal in a sin offering is innocent and ritually clean.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for this excellent contribution.  Would you be able to provide some Bible references for this?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers make good points, to which I would like to add the following:

Jesus offended people

Matthew 15:10-12
10 And he called the people to him and said to them, “Hear and understand: 11 it is not what goes into the mouth that defiles a person, but what comes out of the mouth; this defiles a person.” 12 Then the disciples came and said to him, “Do you know that the Pharisees were offended when they heard this saying?”
...
The Pharisees took offense at Jesus' teaching. To them it was scandalous: he was an obstruction in the path that they were following, and there was no way they would follow him. Indeed, for those who insist on pursuing righteousness by the works of the law, in their own strength, and by their own effort, Jesus is a stumbling block. In effect the Pharisees were saying, We are not sick, and we do not need a doctor, so why are you here?

Thus, Jesus became the reason for those Jewish people who had pledged their allegiance to the law to stumble. He became the reason for them to further reject the word of God and to disobey God. When he corrected their misinterpretation of the law and criticized the evils inherent in their tradition, they were incensed and no way would they accept him.

Their king had come to them, but they would not recognize him. They wanted him to submit to them, but he called them to submit to him. And in rejecting him and arranging for him to be crucified, they demonstrated their own blindness and wickedness and need for forgiveness.

But from before the foundation of the world God had amazingly planned to provide forgiveness through the evil they would do to Jesus; God would provide a cleansing that would come through Jesus' blood and through faith in him. And God had done something similar long before Jesus appeared: two millennia before, in the time when Israel was just a single man with a dozen sons and those sons gathered together to do evil to the one named Joseph. Jesus and the cross parallel the experience of Israel's son Joseph with his brothers - he offended them and they meant to do him evil; but God meant it for good, to bring to pass the salvation of many people.

Some people will be offended by Jesus and offended even by anyone who mentions following Jesus. They will be offended at the idea that people need the cross of Christ. But there will be mercy for those who avail themselves of the forgiveness and cleansing that come through Jesus. As for Israel, she must mourn for putting to death the son whom God sent her. And all of us are called to repent of our exaltation of self, to repent of the worship of things other than God, and to repent of submission to things other than the Lord Jesus. Lord have mercy on us and cleanse us.

Comment: Hello user, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you with us. If you haven't already, please make sure to take our tour, to see how we are a little different from other sites you may know. Thanks! (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour)